# Notifications Never Automatically Appearing In the Field Service Mobile App

Tags: fieldservice

Lets get a couple things out the way:

A rendition of this question has been asked at this address: [Field Service Lightning Mobile Notifications](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239181/field-service-lightning-mobile-notifications) .
However, this constitutes a major functionality and should be addressed.

A trailblazer known posted issue that corresponds to this question can be found at this address:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003URmQAM .
This issue has no fix however.

Essentially, notifications never pop up on their own with the Field Service Mobile App. The only way to get them to appear is to pull down on the notification page, causing a refresh. Anyone have a fix?

Steps I have taken:

1. Installed the connected app.
2. Enabled feed tracking on Service Appointment, Work Order Line Item, and Work Order.
3. Created a trigger to have the user follow feed of their Service Appointments, Work Order Line Items, and Work Orders.
4. Made Record Data Cache Time in Minutes to 15 minutes(so as to spark a quicker data refresh).

All in all, I've tried a lot of different things here and nothing seems to work. In my perspective, this makes the function of a notification pointless.